# Cannot pass url in html code

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I cannot pass URL in html code.  I want to do like this :

eg. 
**http://www.myname.com/page.aspx?id=1&name=test&msg=

message message message**

If I do like that then **The page cannot be found**.

I also try like this:
**http://www.myname.com/page.aspx?id=1&name=test&msg=%3Cp%3Emessage%20message%20message%3C/p%3E**

but still cannot.  I try in my localhost.  It is Okay but if I upload in my server this method will not work.

So how I can pass URL in html code?

Comment: Is this a standard 404 error? If so then make sure page.aspx actually exists by navigating to http://www.myname.com/page.aspx

Answer (score 1):

"The page cannot be found"

Have you tried navigating to the page without the extra stuff?

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt look URL friendly to me but perhaps this guide will make it reader ok and properly URL encoded http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_urlencode.asp

Im thinking ur looking for

```
response.write(Server.URLEncode("http://www.myname.com/page.aspx?id=1&name=test&msg=message message message"))
```

Just Be aware that spaces are generally bad in URLS as with some Special Characters as well You don't want to trust user input to output as URL i reckon